# How can a line make intercepts on $x$-axis,$y$-axis and $z$-axis?

Tags: vectors, 3d

I am preparing for my Mathematics Exam. While studying Three Dimension Geometry I encountered a question in my textbook which is :

*Find the equation of a line which passes through point $(2,3,4)$ and which has equal intercepts on the axes.*

I am not able to solve the question because I doubt how can a line intersect all the three axes. To do so it has to bend, then it will not be a line.

Comment: What do you mean by equal intercepts? Does it mean it just intercepts with all three axes?

Comment: I copied the question as it is in the book. Even I feel ambiguity. This is the reason I seek help of you all

Comment: The elephant in the room is, the difference between `intercept` and `intersect`!

Comment: @polfosol If a line does not intersect then how can it make an intercept on any of the three axes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doesn't any line through the origin do the trick?

Comment: I am sorry. I am not getting what you want to say.

Comment: pick the line that passes through $(0,0,0)$ and $(2,3,4)$ and you are done.

Comment: That is not working. Direction ratio in the answer is (1,1,1). By your method we are getting D.R. as (2,3,4).

Comment: Yes. Even I doubt the answer given in the book cause what you told is reasonable. Thanks.

Comment: you are welcome, I'm happy to discuss further if you'd like.

Comment: I will surely seek further help if needed.

Comment: you can also write it as $v+\lambda u$ where $u$ and $v$ are vectors and $\lambda$ ia a variable that takes real values